# matplotlib plt functions do not work when I am running the script from cmd

Tags: python, matplotlib, cmd, spyder

I wrote a programme to plot some data,the programme works perfectly when I run it from Spyder IDE, however, when I run it from the windows cmd it crashes and doesn't respond to plt functions!!
any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: This can have a million different reasons. You need to find the [mcve] of a script that shows this behaviour and post it here (by [edit]ing your question). Also post the code line you use to run the scrit. Also provide as much information as you can on your system (versions of python, matplotlib, spyder, windows).

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I had this issue as I have my spyder IDE set to run on Python 3.xx and my windows cmd runs Python 2.7.  I would make sure you are running the correct version of Python in your cmd window.